# Laravel Migration Error on foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, foreign-keys, schema

I have a problem running the migration of my Laravel project. When I run artisan migrate, it stops in the foreign key. Can someone help me with this? I tried the solution on the other similar questions but it does not work.

> Error Message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table.

`airways`.`#sql-4588_cfb` **(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**  **(SQL: alter table `flights` add constraint `flights_airport_departure_foreign`
foreign key (`airport_departure`) references `airports` (`airport_code`) on delete cascade)**

***flights_table.php***

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('flight_number')->primary();
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->integer('airport_departure')->unsigned();
            $table->string('departure_time');
            $table->integer('airport_arrival')->unsigned();
            $table->string('arrival_time');
            $table->string('flight_duration');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('flights', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('airport_departure')
                  ->references('airport_code')->on('airports')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');

                  $table->foreign('airport_arrival')
                  ->references('airport_code')->on('airports')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

***airports_table.php***

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('airports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('airport_code')->primary();
            $table->string('airport_name');
            $table->string('airport_location');
            $table->string('airport_state');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check your order of migration. It's needed to migrate the airports table first and then the flights table.

Comment: so theres nothing wrong with my code sir?

Comment: It seems not. Check the timestamps of your both migration file. If flights migration timestamp is bigger than the airports table make it less than the airports table.

Comment: how could I migrate the airports table first sir before the flights table? is there any command to do it? All I know is `php artisan migrate` which migrates my configured database.

Comment: In your migrations folder check the orders of migration. Which one is up in the list?

Comment: the first is airports table then planes then flights. Its like this `users`>`password_resets`>`airports`>`planes`>`flights`

Comment: my flights table is now less than than the airports table sir, but still gets me the same error

Comment: try removing unsigned method from foreign keys column `$table->integer('airport_departure')->unsigned();`

Comment: Which one you are using? InnoDB or myIsam?

Comment: im not sure sir. But im using XAMPP for my database and mysql so I think its InnoDB

Comment: its the same error sir when i removed the `unsigned();` method

Comment: @Vince, codebuilders already gave answer to your question. but I think you just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key column types are wrong. You're not setting the airport_code as an unsigned integer but airport_departure and airport_arrival are expecting unsigned integers. Also you'll need to create the airports table before creating flights table, not the other way 'round as suggested by others.

Comment: I see. So I need to add `unsigned` in my `airport_code` column. Its now `$table->integer('airport_code')->primary()->unsigned();` And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback your migration, change the order of migration i.e if the airport table is 2014_10_12_0000 and the flights_table is 2014_10_12_00001, change airport table to 0002.

Comment: i rolledback my migration sir but when i execute migrate command it still gets the same error.

Comment: I already make a changes in my migration file sir. The airports table timestamps is now greater than the flights table. And still it gets me the same error.